# Why does a Card widget not wrap all the items inside a Wrap widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Initially,** I created a Column to show all of the inner elements like a Container Widget with an image, an icon, texts. The Column widget **squashes the interior items, so I changed the Column to a Wrap widget**; it solved the problem.

**However,** when I tried to set onPressed/onTap logic **only half of the items were clickable in the vertical axis**. As an experiment, I wrapped the Wrap widget with a Card widget to see what area is covered. **It turns out that the Card widget was covering exactly only that vertical part that was clickable.**

**To visualize this I am providing this screenshot of a UI**

[image]

I tried:

1. *Setting up a container with a fixed size to change the Card widget geometry*
2. *Setting up a sized box and following steps like in 1.*
3. *Setting expandables to interior elements*

These are some of the solutions I used, however, none of them worked.

**So what are suggestions as to what may cause this problem? And what can be a solution?**

Code is provided here:

```
Widget _buildWomanProductContainer({
required double width,
required double height,
required String imagePath,
required String clothProductName,
required String clothType,
required String clothPrice,}) {
return InkWell(
  onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => WomenProductScreen(),
  )),
  child: Card(
    child: Wrap(
      alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 0),
        Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: width,
              height: height,
              child: Image.asset(
                imagePath,
                width: width,
                height: height,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                colorBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              right: 5,
              bottom: 5,
              child: IconButton(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite,
                    size: 30, color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1)),
                onPressed: () => {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: const Text('Сохранено'),
                    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                  ))
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            Text(clothProductName,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 67, 59, 1),
                  fontFamily: 'Merriweather-Regular',
                )),
            Text(clothType,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 67, 59, 0.5),
                    fontFamily: 'Merriweather-Regular',
                    fontSize: 12)),
            OutlinedButton(
              child: Text(clothPrice,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 67, 59, 1),
                      fontFamily: 'SolomonSans-SemiBold')),
              onPressed: () =>
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: const Text('Сохранено'),
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
              )),
              style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                side: BorderSide(
                    width: 1.0, color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 67, 59, 1)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);}
```

UPDATE

[image]

Comment: Why dont you use Column instead of Wrap widget?

Comment: Because then the "bottom overflowed by 123 pixels" error appears; wrap widget solves this problem but card is not expanded because of this harsh solution

Comment: Did you try `BoxFit.fill` instead of `cover`

Comment: Adding BoxFit.fill does not make changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Card(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 20, vertical: 40),
                    elevation: 5,
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/image.jpeg',
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    right: 15,
                    bottom: 35,
                    child: IconButton(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.favorite,
                          size: 30, color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1)),
                      onPressed: () => {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          content: const Text('Сохранено'),
                          duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                        ))
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Text('Product name',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 67, 59, 1),
                  fontFamily: 'Merriweather-Regular',
                )),
            Text('type',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 67, 59, 0.5),
                    fontFamily: 'Merriweather-Regular',
                    fontSize: 12)),
            OutlinedButton(
              child: Text('10000',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 67, 59, 1),
                      fontFamily: 'SolomonSans-SemiBold')),
              onPressed: () =>
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: const Text('Сохранено'),
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
              )),
              style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                side: BorderSide(
                    width: 1.0, color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 67, 59, 1)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tested this code on the smallest possible device and there is no pixel overflows. The thing is you have wrap your `Stack` widget inside the `Expanded` and it will take the maximum available space. No need to use `Wrap` widget in your case.
Screenshot:[image]

Comment: How to increase the height of the image in this code setup? Check the post for the updated screenshot of what it looks now